# Inclusive Security Filters in Business Central

Tags: dynamics-business-central, permissionset, security-filter

I need to grant row-level access to a table based on two calculated flowfields, and the user should be able to access the record if either of them is true. For example:

```
    field(101; CanSeeThisRecordA; Boolean)
    {
    }
    field(102; CanSeeThisRecordB; Boolean)
    {
    }
```

I can set a security filter to allow all records with `CanSeeThisRecordA = true`, and I can set one with the other field, but using both will only display records where both fields are true.
Exclusion Permission Sets apparently ignore security filters and block the whole table.
It also seems impossible to create some kind of calculated field that just equals `A or B` in a boolean manner.
I cannot find any way to get the expected behaviour I would get when using for example `FilterGroup(-1)` in code.